# Can you reach to embedded tags variable from outside?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I need to get the index of a th:each to outsider scope.

```
   <div th:object="userList">
        <form th:action="@{/api/v1/product/saveProductToUser/{username}/{productName}(username=${userList.get(iterstatus).getUserName()},productName=${productList.get(${iterstatus2})})}" th:object="productList"   id="register" class="input-group" method="post">

          <select class="input-opt">
            <option th:each="a,iterStatus : ${productList}" th:text="${a.productName}" th:value="${a.productName}" th:with="iterstatus2=${iterStatus}" id="opt2">Choose a Product</option>
          </select >

          <select  class="input-opt">
            <option th:each="a,iterStatus : ${userList}" th:text="${a.userName}" th:value="${a.userName}"  th:with="iterstatus=${iterStatus}" id="opt2">Choose a Product</option>
          </select >

          <a th:href="@{/api/v1/product/showAllProducts}" type="submit" class="submit-btn">Save</a>
```

Can I get the index of this iteration to my **form**? Or any alternative solutions?

Comment: Maybe you can explain a bit more about why you want to do this. And what do you mean by "this iteration"? Do you mean you want a specific index value to be returned along with each selected option? I am not sure how that information can help you.

Comment: I thought **Can I get the index of this iteration to my form?** this sentence is very self explanatory. But no problem. I want to get the index of for loop to my form. That form is wrapping the select tag and my for loop is in select tag. @andrewJames

Comment: Yes, that is clear already from your question. But why do you want to do this?

Comment: I will use that index to send the selected username to my controller. @andrewJames

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. You should send the user name to the controller - or, if that is not guaranteed to be unique then send whatever unique ID you have already defined _at source_ (where the user name was defined) - for example, from a database. In other words, provide the unique identifier _to_ Thymeleaf. Don't expect Thymeleaf to generate it for you.

Comment: Having said that, if you really still want to pursue this, then provide it in option's `value` attribute - because that is what your form will use when sending data to the controller. This is why I said "_I am not sure how that information can help you_".

Comment: `@RequestMapping(path = "/saveProductToUser/{username}/{productName}")
    public RedirectView saveProductToUser(@PathVariable("username") String username,@PathVariable("productName") String productName){

        productService.addProductToUser(productName,username);
        RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView();
        redirectView.setUrl("http://localhost:8093/api/v1/product/showAllProducts");
        return redirectView;
    }` ** I have to return this parameters via thymeleaf. But it seems that i can't reach that index from the container. Do you have any possible solution